# Show Real-Valued function $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+|x|}$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Show that the real-valued function $f\colon\Bbb R^2\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ defined by $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+|x|}$.

What is $f(\Bbb R^n)$?
Is it true that a real valued function always maps ${\left\lbrace
\matrix{\text{an} & \text{open} & \text{set}\cr \text{a} & \text{closed} &\text{set}}
\right\rbrace}$ to ${\left\lbrace\matrix{\text{an} & \text{open} & \text{set}\cr \text{a} & \text{closed} &\text{set}}
\right\rbrace}$?

Can the Triangle Inequality be used?

Comment: What you say about real valued function mapping is not true. Consider the function $f:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ with $f(x) = 1$ for all $x\in \Bbb R^n$. Then no open set is mapped to an open set. In general topology, however, the usual definition of a continious function $f:X\to Y$ is that for any open set $U\subseteq Y$, we have that $f^{-1}(U)\subseteq X$ is open. The same goes for closed.

Answer (score 3):

**Counter examples:**

$1$: $\mathbb{R}$ is closed, but using $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ via $f(x) = e^x$, $f(R) = (0, ∞)$ is not closed.

Note that $(-1, 1)$ is open, but $f :  (-1, 1)\to R$ via $f(x) = x^{2}$, 
$f(-1, 1))= [0, 1)$ is not open.

In topology, an open map is a function between two topological spaces which maps open sets to open sets. That is, a function $f : X \to Y$ is open if for any open set $U $in X, the image $f(U)$ is open in Y. Likewise, a closed map is a function which maps closed sets to closed sets.

**Every homeomorphism is open, closed, and continuous.**